# Java: Loop thought the list, then check the results with if else

Tags: java, android

I have situation where I have Arraylist, which has name items in it. I need to loop through that namelist which check if the new name that user gave, is already on a list or not. If it is, just give toast to notify user that name is already there, or if it isn't, then add name to the list.

This is what I have:

```
public class ActivityPlayers extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static ArrayList<NameItem> mNameList;

    private Button buttonAdd;
    private EditText textAdd;

    private int checkNumber;


        /** When "add" button been clicked... **/
        textAdd = findViewById(R.id.name_input);
        buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                /** Loop the list **/
                for (int i = 0; i < mNameList.size(); i++) {

                    /** Check if user input match to any name in list 
                    and if it does...**/
                    if (mNameList.get(i).getText1().equals(textAdd.toString().trim())) {
                        checkNumber = 1;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        /** If it doesn't **/
                        checkNumber = 0;
                    }
                }

                /** if checkNumber is still 0 **/
                if (checkNumber == 0) {
                    /** Close soft keyboard **/
                    InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager)
                            getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                            InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

                    /** ...add a name to the namelist **/
                    addItem(0);
                } else {
                    /** if name in a list == name from input, give toast **/
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Name is already on a list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Any ideas why this won't work? It only adds the names to the list, even tho it already exists... but it never detects duplicates...

Answer (score 2):

`if (mNameList.get(i).getText1().equals(textAdd.toString().trim()))`

In the above line of code you compare the *i*th list element to the string representation of the EditText itself, not to its Text field. Instead of `textAdd.toString()`, you should use `textAdd.getText()`.

Unrelated to the problem, but I suggest using `boolean` variables to represent logical flags in your code instead of integer counting.
In the above example, it would go like this:

```
private boolean nameInList = false;
//...
if (...) {
    nameInList = true;
    break;
}
//...
if (nameInList) {
    //...
} else {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (mNameList.get(i).getText1().equalsIgnoreCase(textAdd.getText().toString().trim())) {
    checkNumber = 1;
    break;
} else {
    /** If it doesn't **/
    checkNumber = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use a suitable data structure *Set* which disallows duplicate values. You will also have saved your self from loops.

create a set object for example
`Set<String> names = new TreeSet();` call the *add()* which returns true if name doesn't exist in set, else false meaning name exists.

```
Set<String> names = TreeSet();
boolean isExists = names.add("my name");
if(isExists){ // make you toast here}
```